# What is the reason for returning int when it's actually void?

Tags: c, linux, api, linux-kernel, void

I faced with some strange (for me) code in Linux kernel sources. There is [`xt_register_target()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14-rc2/source/net/netfilter/x_tables.c#L75) function:

```
int xt_register_target(struct xt_target *target)
{
    u_int8_t af = target->family;

    mutex_lock(&xt[af].mutex);
    list_add(&target->list, &xt[af].target);
    mutex_unlock(&xt[af].mutex);
    return 0;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(xt_register_target);
```

This is an API function. So it seems that it must have some obvious (for API user) reason for the value it returns. But this function has no variability - it always returns 0. So basically it is `void`.
What is the reason for such API coding pattern? Is this best practice or a mistake?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Digging into the git history, it seems this function did previously have failure conditions but those conditions were later removed in [this commit](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/7926dbfa4bc14e27f4e18a6184a031a1c1e077dc#diff-04cfc5dac38720ad1ed97fe25480a05bd55df5f6d5093f0174966adf1ecc7a73).

So it made sense to keep the function's implementation the same to prevent changes to calling functions.